# numpy, scipy, pass large number of variables between functions, modules, easily

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

so i'm using numpy, scipy, matplotlib for scientific computing, running some simulations and trying to do modularized operations on them, and i'm running into issues. trying to adapt my workflow from matlab.

in matlab, i would typically write several functions spread out over separate files- one that runs a simulation with parameters as arguments, one that runs evaluations on the results of those simulations from feeding different parameter values in, a separate function that plots results and titles according to parameters, etc. typically the parameter sets and the result sets would be very large combinations of differently typed variables, so i would pack them into structures. there's a function in matlab called v2struct that makes it easy to pack and unpack these combinations of variables between the different operations i would run. also, i don't seem to run into issues with namespaces in matlab.

now in python, i want to be able to do these same kinds of things. i'm slowly learning how to write classes but i can't find very good documentation on how to organize these in my file system. since i'm more comfortable writing functions and scripts (i think this is the correct terminology) and running them with ipython %run script.py` i would like to leverage the same kind of capability of passing large numbers of parameters and results variables between various functions to run simulations, test the outcomes and plot the results. this is why i've been trying to pack things into dictionaries, and then unpack them in other namespaces. this would make it 100% easier for me to break up code scripts i've done to pilot these simulations into modular pieces.

but every time i try to figure out how to do it i see a lot of "no one should ever be dynamically creating variables" and "i can't imagine why you would ever want to unpack a dictionary." what's the point of passing dictionaries around functions then?? i'm expecting a lot of different functions that work with the same variable sets. yes, i know this means classes. but they're really hard to design, at least for scientific computing. or maybe just for me. is there some middle ground?

does anyone have any links to any tutorials that teach you how to get around this? resources to teach you how to design code (aka i understand how to use python to script from the 90 billion "intro to python" tutorials out there, but there's a gap with figuring out how to turn my scripts into modules, ie refactor). i know how to write a class, but not how to choose how to put my scripts into classes, or when to divide things up into subclasses, or in particular, how to use a class i've made with one of my scripts.

---

OK here's the solution I've landed on:
breaking up my script (that all shares one one namespace) into functions (that work on the same variables, but in different namespaces) I make a keylist, `('tuple','of','keys')` that i use to pack variables from my function namespace into an output dictionary:

```
returnVals = dict();
for k in keylist:
    returnVals[k]=locals()[k]

return returnVals
```

To make things even easier (i hope) on myself I pack the argument names into the keylist automatically like so:

```
argNames = my_function.func_code.co_varnames[:my_function.func_code.co_argcount]
```

and then `keynames = argNames + ('stuff','function','computes')`

The only thing that's a little annoying is having to rewrite all the variable names in the function arguments ( ie `def subfunction(sameVarName1,sameVarName2,etc):`) 
so that when i call `subfunction(**whateverINamedMyReturnValsInLastFunction)` the function knows what keys are going to be in the kwargs. But, I figure that's going to help me in the long run when I (hopefully) am able to reuse my code.

Comment: This may also be a good use case for classes.  A class in Python at least is, afterall, mostly just a dictionary with some additional structure tacked on to it.  Data shared between different functions can class attributes so that any method that needs it has access to it.

Comment: MATLAB structures roughly match with Python dictionaries; cells with lists.  Classes are built into Python, not a late add on.  Module namespaces are also central to Python organization.

Comment: You might experiment with passing data from MATLAB programs with .mat files - using the scipy.io.loadmat function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally agree with "no one should ever be dynamically creating variables"
but strong disagree with "i[sic] can't imagine why you would ever want to unpack
a dictionary."<sup>[1]</sup>

[Unpacking a dictionary](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) is a very nice way to solve your current problem:

```
def foo():
    result = dict()
    # fill `result` with values
    result[key] = value
    ...
    return result

def bar(arg1, arg2, ...):
    ...

result = foo()
bar(**result)
```

The last line unpacks the key/value pairs in `result` and passes them to `bar` as arguments.

```
bar(**{key1:value1, key2:value2})
```

is equivalent to

```
bar(key1=value1, key2=value2)
```

---

I don't think [you really need to define a class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) just to pass values around. A dictionary will do.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>Well, on second thought, it depends on what is meant by "unpacking a dictionary". Unpacking a dictionary to the global namespace is bad idea, but unpacking a dictionary to a function is fine.

Comment: Dear lord this helps tremendously. I had run across **kwargs before but missed the distinction of having to have the variable names you're going to wind up unpacking in the function arguments. I guess otherwise the function doesn't know that kwargs['x'] is going to ever get assigned, so it generates a name error.  Now I'm doing something hacky to pack it all up real fast-  `return locals()`. This makes the script refactoring much, much easier. but i should probably think about garbage cleanup or something, yeah?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind with garbage cleanup. But one thing to keep
in mind is that if you `return locals()`, the `result = foo()` dict may have
more key/value pairs than you need to pass to `bar`. You *could* use `def
bar(arg1, arg2, **kwargs)` to allow you to call `bar(**result)` *without*
cleaning up the extra key/value pairs -- the `**kwargs` will happily swallow
everything extra.

Comment: Note, however, that while this may help you refactor quickly, this is also
sloppy programming which could lead to a somewhat hard to find silent error
because `bar(**result)` will not raise an error if you pass a `result` dict with
a misspelt key.

Comment: OK! i'm selecting the appropriate variables by making an output keylist and updating my return list with only the `locals()[key]` items. I think that should let me get rid of the **kwargs in my function definitions which is good if I'm going to be changing arguments a lot. It seems to work so far-- haven't battle tested it yet, but I'm feeling a lot less frustrated with this language (for now, haha!). Thanks for all your help!